# Running same C# application twice

Tags: c#, visual-studio, settings, solution

The application is a form application and it is too complicated. It is mostly used to connect to a database with an user interface. It also uses third party dlls.

I copied my VS C# application`s bin folder to my desktop.

> "C:\Users\asd\Desktop\bin"

After that, I made some changes in my solution and building it, I again copied the application`s bin file under C:\;

> "C:\bin"

Now when I run **"C:\Users\asd\Desktop\bin\Debug\LIVE.exe"** and let it remain open I can`t run **"C:\bin\Debug\LIVE.exe"**. There is no error when I try to open the second .exe file. It simply does nothing.

I want both of the applications to be open at the same time.

Comment: Depends what your application is doing. Does it open any files? Ports? Other resources?

Comment: Who can say from here. Run the one from the desktop, and then run the other from Visual Studio.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is a form application and it is too complicated. It is mostly used to connect to a database with an user interface. The application also uses third party dlls. Isn`t there are simple way to open the same application twice ?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I tried that also, it acts as the same way.

Comment: If some resource is used by the program can be only once - no. Think of, say, serial port. You just can't open it twise, since it is a physical single resource.

Comment: perhaps there are some `Mutex` code in one or many of the .dll's why are you wanting to launch it more than once anyway..?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I see, the program uses database connection string to reach some data. I believe this is not the problem.

Comment: @MethodMan Its because the application running from the desktop is an exe file and the codes for that application is missing. I have the old codes and after I made some changes I copied the bin folder under C:, I need both of them running on the same time.

Comment: Put a debug in program.cs, and step into the code from there. The only other possibility aside from contention over resources is you did not copy the exe to the desktop, you created a shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the application, there are ways to prevent execution of a second instance (I have actually implemented the described behaviour in production code) so check the production specs of the application to see if that's a desired behaviour on client machines.

Because it's using a database connection and third party DLLs, there may be other specific limitations in place preventing proper execution, so check whether any exceptions are being cuaght by hooking into the `FirstChanceException` (WARNING: Never use this code outside a debug context!)

```
#if DEBUG
static Program()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, e) => { };
}
#endif
```

Insert this into your `Program` class, or whichever class houses the `Main` method (and rename it if it's not `Program` of course) and then breakpoint the opening of the handler - this will often catch lots of exceptions you're better off not worrying about, but it may also clue you in if there is a problem keeping your code from starting.

As always, make sure to run this from within VS's Debug, so as to see any exceptions as they occur.